# Latitude & Longitude Not Retrieved

Tags: ios, core-location

UPDATED for iOS9: I am new to iOS, experimenting with CoreLocation to return latitude and longitude values. The following code never executes the log output

```
 -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc]init];

manager.delegate = self;
manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

[manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Here is my  didUpdateToLocation function with is never reached

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{

NSLog(@"Location: %@", locations);
CLLocation *currentLocation = locations.lastObject;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    float latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    float longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;

    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", longitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", latitude);
}

else{ NSLog(@"ERROR");
    }
```

}

Comment: Use actual device and not simulator

Comment: you need to implement `CLLocationManager` delegate which provides you lat long info. you can't directly get it. For more details refer [apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/index.html)

Comment: @sam-b I am testing on a device, I also updated my code for iOS 9 and am still having an issue

Answer (score 1):

`CLLocationManager` is asynchronous, You should get the latitude and longitude in the delegate method.

`locationManager.delegate = self;`

Then implement this delegate method:

`- locationManager:didUpdateLocations:`

Comment: So, I need to move my code to locationManager:didUpdateLocations ?

Comment: @themotjuste move this code to delegate mothod.                                           float latitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude;
float longitude = locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude;

NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", longitude);
NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", latitude);

Comment: For some reason, the app never reaches the delegate method

Comment: Declared locationManager as property or global variable.

Answer (score 1):

1.first of all, you should use you should use a actual device instead of a simulator

2.implement CLLocationManagerDelegate in the interface,like

```
@interface XXXXX () <CLLocationManagerDelegate>
```

3.after

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
```

add

```
locationManager.delegate = self;
```

4.implement the delegate method

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations
{
    for (CLLocation *location in locations) {
        //you can get locations here

    }
}
```

Comment: I updated my code to show my new didUpdateLocation function, but it's not being reached. Also, I am testing on my device.