# CoreLocation iOS9 storing Coordinates

Tags: ios, mobile, core-location

I recently asked this question, not knowing of the changes made to CL in iOS 9. I am trying to store the user's current location and I have changed my code to reflect the new delegate methods in iOS 9, but didUpdateLocations is still never reached.

Here is the link to my original question: [Latitude & Longitude Not Retrieved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34192331/latitude-longitude-not-retrieved/34192389?noredirect=1#comment56138758_34192389)

And my updated code:

viewWillAppear

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{

manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
manager.delegate = self;

if ([manager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {
    [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}
[manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

didUpdateLocations

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
 didUpdateLocations:(NSArray<CLLocation *> *)locations{

NSLog(@"Location: %@", locations);
CLLocation *currentLocation = locations.lastObject;

if (currentLocation != nil) {
    float latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;

    float longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;


    NSLog(@"dLongitude : %f", longitude);
    NSLog(@"dLatitude : %f", latitude);
}

else{ NSLog(@"ERROR");
     }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check for

```
authorizationStatus and startUpdatingLocation
```

and

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status
```

you can also go to settings ->privacy -> location services (turn on) -> select ur app and select while using.

Comment: My location services are toggled on, but I do not see my app listed

Comment: have you added key in plist?

Comment: adding NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription or NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription key in Info.plist with a message to be displayed in the prompt. Adding these will solve your problem.